# ¿Por qué hablamos inglés en un foro dedicado al español?

Tags: discusión

No entiendo como hay más preguntas escritas en inglés que en español.

Comment: Cabe notar que el nombre del sitio no es «Intercambio de pilas: lengua castellana ».

Comment: Esta pregunta debería estar en Meta

Comment: http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/313/porqu%C3%A9-discutir-muchas-cosas-del-lenguaje-en-ingles-en-lugar-de-en-espa%C3%B1ol

Comment: Aunque en meta se deben dar las discusiones en ingles siempre que sea posible, pq muchas de estas discusiones el equipo tecnico de stack exchange necesia entenderlas.

Comment: Yo creo que sería genial cambiar 100% a Español... pero por el momento, todo el UI está en inglés, y así es difícil decir que solo podemos hablar español aquí. Pero cuando cambien a español para el UI también, espero que podemos cambiar todo a español.

Comment: Te digo que en [Chinese Stackexchange](http://meta.chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/345/your-input-do-we-allow-questions-and-answers-written-completely-in-chinese/346#346) el único idioma aceptable es inglés... lo que me aparece absolutamente loco. En mi opinión deberíamos aceptar preguntas en inglés para los novatos, los que son muchos, y también las en el idioma del sitio para los estudiantes más avanzados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the 5 year old question from meta stack exchange: [Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange) which gives some interesting perspectives on this.

To be fair, this was back when the Stack Exchange network was first set up, and was focused on programming and other technical related subjects, where having a single lingua franca, English, makes a lot of sense.

My personal view is that for language specific sites, such as this one, it is reasonable to ask/answer in either English or the language in question.

Comment: Estoy totalmente de acuerdo pero no pude encontrar la norma específica

Comment: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic dale un poco de scroll y llegaras a **¿Debería escribir en español o en inglés?**

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 7):

Porque mucha gente que intenta aprender español se expresa mejor y más claramente en inglés, bien porque es su idioma nativo o bien porque lo ha aprendido antes que el español (bastante habitual)